# Omitting big objects when pickling in python

Tags: python, pickle

In the object I have reference to some other, big object.
Is it possible to pickle only first object omitting the big one?

Is it possible with JSON or other marshaling?

Comment: Some example code would help :) otherwise it seems like a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [pickle protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle-protocol)

You can implement [`__getstate__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) and [`__setstate__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__).

With `__getstate__` you can delete whatever you don't want from the object dictionary.